# Does any RDBMS parallelize or otherwise optimize UNION queries?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, postgresql, oracle

For an example data set with rows fulfilling both subqueries:

```
SELECT h.batch, li.id as line_item, d.prusr as price, 0 as advertised
FROM schema.lineitem li
INNER JOIN schema.detail d on d.line = li.line and d.item = li.item
INNER JOIN schema.header h on d.batch = h.batch
LEFT JOIN schema.specialoffer sp ON sp.LINE = d.LINE AND sp.ITEM = d.ITEM
WHERE h.status = 'T' AND sp.batch IS NULL

UNION ALL
SELECT h.batch, li.id as line_item, d.prusr as price, 1 as advertised
FROM schema.lineitem li
INNER JOIN schema.detail d on d.line = li.line and d.item = li.item
INNER JOIN schema.header h on d.batch = h.batch
INNER JOIN schema.specialoffer sp ON sp.LINE = d.LINE AND sp.ITEM = d.ITEM
WHERE h.status = 'T'
```

What RDBMS will attempt to parallelize this type of query? I'd also be interested in any other "under the hood" sorts of optimizations you may know of, but parallelization is the main focus of this question.

References I have found already:

- **MySQL**: No - [Can MySQL parallelize UNION subqueries (or anything at all)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6896071/1701316)
- **Oracle**: Maybe - [Does a database parallelize a SQL query which has a union in it?](https://www.quora.com/Does-a-database-parallelize-a-SQL-query-which-has-a-union-in-it/answer/Senthilnathan-Athinarayanan)

Comment: By the way, why is this written as a UNION, when you could have it as a simple LEFT JOIN (removing the `AND sp.batch IS NULL` part)?

Comment: If each arm of a `UNION` is I/O bound, parallelism may be useless for performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Can each section of `UNION`/`UNION ALL` run concurrently?*

## Oracle

YES ([oracle 12c+](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-1F4C90F9-3EF5-423A-B55B-2593FB3F1433.htm))

## MySQL

NO ([per OP's question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6896071/1701316))

## PostgreSQL

No for Postgres 10 or earlier
Yes for [Postgres 11](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/parallel-plans.html#PARALLEL-APPEND) currently in Beta

## Microsoft SQL Server

Mostly **no**, when `UNION ALL` is implemented by a *Concatenation* operator. Although not documented (or guaranteed), Concatenation has been observed to always read from its inputs in sequence. Each input may be processed using multiple threads of execution. There *may* be a period of time where threads from different instances are reading from different inputs as processing moves from one input to the next.
Somewhat **yes**, when `UNION ALL` is implemented by a *Concatenation* operator and the inputs reside on different servers (`Open()` calls are performed asynchronously - [*Async Concat* operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/showplan-logical-and-physical-operators-reference?view=sql-server-2017)). How much processing occurs during `Open()` depends on plan shape.
Mostly **yes** when `UNION` or `UNION ALL` is implemented by a *Merge Join Concatenation* operator, since each instance (thread) reads from any input as needed to perform an order-preserving union.

*Are there other "under the hood" sorts of optimizations?*

There are several approaches found in literature regarding common subexpression identification: detecting the same expression in two or more union subqueries. Having done so, you can either use the following equivelence: `(A join B join C) union (A join B join D) -> A join B join (C union D)` to push union before joins when you estimate that this plan will be cheaper, or use methods from an area known as multi-query optimization (here obviously we have a single query, but we can regard different subqueries as separate queries) in order to reuse an expression. Again the decision to reuse an expression is not trivial, as doing so often requires materializing the intermediate result and can lead to much worse execution times. Also, in case that several complex common expressions exist in the subqueries, deciding which one should be materialized (or even which subexpression of an expression) affects the decisions for the rest, making the search space during optimization [doubly exponential](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=335419). In any case, examining these issues heavily affects optimization time, and although there are promising research prototypes, I believe that most commercial products do not consider this kind of optimization. Also note that using such methods results in the whole query being "less-parallelizable", as you can no longer execute each subquery completely independently.